# Avoid blacklisting of Org-Wide email address

Tags: singleemailmessage

We are using the apex method Messaging.sendEmail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId() in a schedular class to send emails to our customers, But our concern is when sending internet email.. you never want from address: to be anything but the real sender’s email address.
But the complete discrepancy in email address and domain between the From(**smtp06-asg.mta.salesforce.com** ) and Reply-To(**Orgwideemail**) fields might make spam or phishing filters more eager to flag the emails.

How to deal with this situation..

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is set up an SPF record ([Sender Policy Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)) on your own domain (the orgwideemail address, which is your company domain).

When you create an SPF entry against your DNS, you are effectively telling recipients that the named sender (in this case salesforce) is allowed to send mails on behalf of your domain (orgwideemail).

You can find some more specific information about this subject in relation to Salesforce and SPF [here](https://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qid=a1X30000000JqZtEAK)